# Can I tell the airline I want my laptop in my checked luggage?

Tags: air-travel

I'm from Turkey and as you may know it, USA and UK banned passengers from Turkey to use a laptop in the flights. Airlines say laptops can be given to them at boarding time and they will be returned after the flight. I don't want that. Am I entitled to carry my laptop in my checked luggage rather than handing it to the flight crew?

Comment: Are you asking to carry your laptop on board even though it's banned? How do you expect the airline to give you an exception?

Comment: Please note "in my luggage".

Comment: @TolgaOzses it is still not clear what are you asking. If you want to put your laptop in your checked in luggage then do it before checking it in. The ban doesn't talk about that. If you want to do something else then elaborate what do you want to do.

Comment: There is hand luggage and there is hold luggage...

Comment: @Berwyn sorry, I mean "hold luggage".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with putting electronics in your checked luggage. *However*:

1. There are typically limits on Lithium Batteries in checked baggage (e.g., a limit of 100 Wh capacity is common and the battery will need to stay attached to the device). Look this up on the website of your airline!
2. There is very limited (practical) liability by the airline in case your laptop breaks.
3. Your bag will be more likely to be subject to manual inspection if it has large quantities of electronics in them.

Comment: Why is there limited liability and what's your cite for no lithium batteries in checked luggage?

Comment: I corrected the battery part - looks like I was not up to date. By limited liability I mean that your checked baggage *will* be thrown around. If your laptop breaks due to that happening, you will have a hard time convincing the airline to pay.

Comment: 4. It will probably get stolen

Comment: @JonathanReez I have sent a small, low value, laptop in checked baggage several times. I pack it towards the middle, surrounded by clothes. No problems so far.

Comment: I've had small electronics stolen from checked luggage for which, after an extensive back and forth between police and airline, the airline sent me a letter, six weeks later, saying that they don't take responsibility for electronics sent in checked in luggage.

Comment: I thought about including this when writing the answer, but saw it covered by point 3 - if it is more likely to be inspected, then it is more likely that baggage handlers know what is in there - hence a higher risk of things getting stolen. Perhaps that was not explicit enough.